# #autocomplete_path not working in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to create a form with a auto-complete textfield for a particular role type usersname. But it's not working. Though when I use "user/autocomplete" which is default path given in example over drupal.org it works...

This is for hook_menu ---

```
function scout_bucks_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['scouts/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'scout_bucks_autocomplete',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('administer scout bucks'),
  ); 
  return $items;
}
```

This id for form --

```
function scoutbucks_add_bucks_form(&$form_state){
  $form = array();
  $form['scout_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title'  => t('Scout Name'),
    '#maxlength' => 60,
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'scouts/autocomplete',
    '#reguired' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#title'  => t('ADD BUCKS TO SCOUT PROFILE'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="submit-button-bucks">',
    '#suffix'   => '</div>',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

This is the function for auto-complete ---

```
function scout_bucks_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $matches = array();
  $userobj = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT users.name, users.uid FROM {users}, {users_roles} WHERE users.uid =  users_roles.uid AND users_roles.rid = 7")); 
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($userobj)) {
    $matches[$row['users.uid']] = $row['users.name'];
  }
  drupal_json($matches);
}
```

What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `drupal_json` to [drupal_to_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_to_js/6).

```
function scout_bucks_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $matches = array();
  $userobj = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT users.name, users.uid FROM {users}, {users_roles} WHERE users.uid =  users_roles.uid AND users_roles.rid = 7")); 
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($userobj)) {
    $matches[$row['users.uid']] = $row['users.name'];
  }
  drupal_to_js($matches); // the edited line.
}
```

Hope this works...

Comment: I had problem because I was not passing the parameter value $string with the query, once I did & got the list. But still it doesn't filter like masqurade do...but give all the names... Still I will try with drupal_to_js and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Sample from working autocomplete on one of my sites:
    function module_menu() {

```
  $items['app/autocomplete/%'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Some title',
    'description'      => '',
    'page callback'    => '_module_autocomplete',
    'page arguments'   => array(2),
    'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
 }

function _module_autocomplete($param) {
    $result = db_query('SELECT id,stuff FROM {table} WHERE a=%d', $param);
    while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $ret[$row->id] = $row->stuff;
    }

    drupal_json($ret);
}
```

I've cut down as much as I feel safe to, but I do think it is bestif you define that % in the menu callback.

Comment: Recently, I've implemented an autocomplete in the same manner to that shown in your answer. The problem I have is that while typing data results in a list of names (stuff), selecting one of them results in the text field displaying the id. Is there any way to have the text field display the name while storing the ID somewhere (id est, a hidden field) or do I have to use a DB query to look up the ID for the name when the form gets submitted?